# Why does gradient equal "None"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using `tape.gradient.(loss, model.trainable_variables)` to get the gradient of the cost function for my GAN, however, it returns an array of `None` values. I initially suspected that either the `loss` or `model.trainable_variables` arguments were erroneous, but I printed them out and they're both defined and seem to be correct. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
```

Basic Model

```
def make_model():
  Model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  Model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, activation='relu'))
  Model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='relu'))
  Model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='relu'))
  return Model
```

Test tensors

```
tensor_one = tf.constant([[4, 5]])

tensor_two  = tf.constant([[9, 3]])
```

Discriminator Model

```
def make_discriminator_model():
    Model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    Model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, activation="relu"))
 
    Model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation="relu"))

    Model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    return  Model
```

Instantiate both models

```
basic_model = make_model()

basic_model(tensor_one)


discriminator_model = make_discriminator_model()

discriminator_model(tensor_one)
```

Create Loss Functions

```
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def model_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss
```

Create Optimizers

```
generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
```

Training Loop

```
epochs = 100

for epoch in range(epochs):
      
      with tf.GradientTape() as model_tape, tf.GradientTape() as discrim_tape:
         
         output_values = basic_model(tensor_one, training=True)

         real_output = discriminator_model(tensor_two, training=True)
         fake_output = discriminator_model(output_values, training=True)

         gen_loss = model_loss(fake_output)
         disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
        
# GET GRADIENTS AND APPLY THEM TO VARIABLES

      gradients_of_model = model_tape.gradient(gen_loss, basic_model.trainable_variables)
      gradients_of_discriminator = discrim_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator_model.trainable_variables)

      print(gradients_of_model)

      generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_model, basic_model.trainable_variables))
      discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator_model.trainable_variables))
```

Link to Google Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PhpJVzuKqZbr9SC7GrJrRp2D5jnVrXT-?usp=sharing

Comment: To elaborate on the objective, I'm trying to create a sort of pseudo-GAN. I say "pseudo" because it doesn't really generate a tensor like an image generation GAN. Rather, it simply updates the weights of an input and then passes it to a discriminator to be verified (and then re-updated accordingly). The idea behind it is to be able to train it to output a sequence (such as [2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0]) by inputting a random tensor of the same shape (such as [4.0,2.0,0.4,1.0,0.5]).

Comment: The problem is your `with` statement.  When the `with` statement ends, `model_tape` and `discrim_tape` will be closed, but you try to use them again.  My advice is to forget about `with` here and just do straight assignments.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did what you recommended, but just got the runtime error "A non-persistent GradientTape can only be used to compute one set of gradients." And adding persistent=True doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is much simpler that what discussed so far.

This is your code:

```py
epochs = 10

for epoch in range(epochs):
  with tf.GradientTape() as model_tape:
    output_values = basic_model(tensor_two, training=True)
    fake_output = discriminator_model(tensor_two, training=True)
    gen_loss = model_loss(fake_output)
  gradients_of_model = model_tape.gradient(gen_loss, basic_model.trainable_variables)
  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_model, basic_model.trainable_variables))
```

Consider calculating the gradient with respect to the generator:

```
grad = dL/dDisc dDisc/dGen
```

However, check the loss you are using to calculate the gradient:

```
gen_loss = model_loss(fake_output)
```

However `fake_output` is a tensor generated by the following line:

```
fake_output = discriminator_model(tensor_two, training=True)
#                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem is that you are passing to the discriminator a tensor which is not the one generated by the generator, thus there is no gradient.

Instead you should do the following:

```py
epochs = 10

for epoch in range(epochs):
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    output_values = basic_model(tensor_two)
    real_output = discriminator_model(tensor_two, training=True)
    fake_output = discriminator_model(output_values)
    gen_loss = model_loss(fake_output)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
  gradients_of_model = tape.gradient(output_values, basic_model.trainable_weights)
  gradients_of_discriminator = tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator_model.trainable_weights)
  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_model, basic_model.trainable_weights))
  discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator_model.trainable_weights))
```

Also consider that the loss is supposed to receive logits, instead you are passing probabilities, so probably better to use:

```
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the tape objects inside the `with`, otherwise they will be closed.  I'm not sure why you need `with` here, anyway.  I'd just do it like this:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
     model_tape = tf.GradientTape()
     discrim_tape = tf.GradientTape()
         
     output_values = basic_model(tensor_one, training=True)

     real_output = discriminator_model(tensor_two, training=True)
     fake_output = discriminator_model(output_values, training=True)

     gen_loss = model_loss(fake_output)
     disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
        
# GET GRADIENTS AND APPLY THEM TO VARIABLES

     gradients_of_model = model_tape.gradient(gen_loss, basic_model.trainable_variables)
     gradients_of_discriminator = discrim_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator_model.trainable_variables)

     print(gradients_of_model)

     generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_model, basic_model.trainable_variables))
     discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator_model.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: Hi! I moved the tape objects inside the `with` but I still get the same error. The discriminator gradient is working fine, it's just the gradient of the first model that's returning "None". The other suggestion of just assigning them directly results in the runtime error "A non-persistent GradientTape can only be used to compute one set of gradients" even if I set `tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)`

Comment: Where is it being used to create another set of gradients?